# Cannot seem to get the value of this input field. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Whenever I run this code in my browser and when I click on one of the buttons I can't seem to get the alert to display the value. It just says undefined. But I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the code:

```
<body>   
  <h1>Optelmachine in Javascript</h1>
     <form id="calculator">
        <textarea name="field" id="field" cols="32" rows="3"></textarea>
        <br> <br>
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="1"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="2"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="3"  onclick="getInputValue()"><br> <br>
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="4"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="5"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="6"  onclick="getInputValue()"><br> <br>
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="7"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="8"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="9"  onclick="getInputValue()"><br> <br>
        <input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="0"  onclick="getInputValue()">
        <input  type="button"  class="waarde1" name="reset"    value="Clear" onclick="addition()">
     </form>
     <script>
        function getInputValue() {
           var inputVal = document.getElementsByName("waarde").value;
           alert(inputVal);
        }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input  type="button"   class="waarde"  name="waarde"   value="0"  onclick="getInputValue(event)">
     </form>
     <script>
        function getInputValue(event) {
           let inputVal = event.target.value
           alert(inputVal);
        }
```

Provided you're expecting to get the value onClick

Comment: @RobG Try passing the event to your function call `onclick="getInputValue(event)"`

Comment: @FilipFilipovic—it's not my function call. ;-) Good to see you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The getElementsByName() function returns an array of elements, not just one element. To get the value of an input field, you would need to specify the index, such as

```
var inputVal = document.getElementsByName("waarde")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getInputValue() {
       var inputVal = this.value;
       alert(inputVal);
    }
```

try this instead. This will alert the value of the clicked button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Buntel/jmnka8uc/5/ here is an working example

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName returns collection of elemets, not single element.
You have to get to know which element was clicked.
Use onclick="getInputValue(event) in your inputs and get value using event.target.value in your function.

Comment: This looks like an exact copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61631459/4068240

Comment: @Clijsters ummmm.. no it doesn't. It essentially says the same thing as the accepted answer. While the comment you're referencing says to get the value by index, this comment advises to get the value by the passed event

Comment: @FilipFilipovicMy link doesn't reference the accepted answer. It refers to answer #4068240 by Icsth.

Comment: @Clijsters I understand that. That's the point. This comment refers to the accepted answer, not the answer you linked. The answer you linked has a way different approach, so I wouldn't call it an 'exact copy'